# How to broadcast an intent if new email is received from any network gmail or other

Tags: android

I have to read the new arrived email in my broadcast receiver for which a want to set a broadcast intent filter in my manifest files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by any email client that I am aware of. It is certainly not a documented feature of the Email or Gmail applications normally associated with Android. Sorry.

Comment: Is there is any thing I can do which can perform this task for me.

Comment: @Jawad: You can write your own email client.